# How to use SwiftUI TextFields for Ints of objects

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I am using swiftui textfields to allow a user to enter certain values that will be sent to a database. The values are entered using a view for each "mySet" Object. An overlying "Session" object (contained in setsViewModel) has an array of these "mySet"s.

Here is the view that allows a user to input values for a given set:

```
struct SetView: View {
    var set_num: Int
    @State var setsViewModel: SetsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Set " + String(set_num+1))
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("Weight")
                    TextField("Lbs", value: $setsViewModel.session.sets[set_num].weight, format: .number)
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Reps")
                    TextField("# Reps", value: $setsViewModel.session.sets[set_num].reps, format: .number)
                }
            }
            HStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("Quality")
                    TextField("1-5", value: $setsViewModel.session.sets[set_num].quality, format: .number)
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Rep Speed")
                    TextField("1-5", value: $setsViewModel.session.sets[set_num].rep_speed, format: .number)
                    
                }
            }
            HStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("Rest Before")
                    TextField("Seconds", value: $setsViewModel.session.sets[set_num].rest_before, format: .number)
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Anything else")
                    TextField(text: $setsViewModel.session.sets[set_num].note, label: { Text("Enter note")})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These SetViews are used in a list in another view called SetsView:

```
struct SetsView: View {
    var workout: Workout
    var exercise: Exercise
    var session_id: Int
    @State var setsViewModel: SetsViewModel
    
    init(workout: Workout, exercise: Exercise, session_id: Int) {
        self.workout = workout
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.session_id = session_id

        self.setsViewModel = SetsViewModel(session_id: session_id, workout_id: workout.workout_id, exercise: exercise)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                ForEach(0..<exercise.set_number) {set_index in
                    SetView(set_num: set_index, setsViewModel: setsViewModel)
                }
                submitButton
            }
        }.navigationTitle(exercise.exercise_name)
    }
    
    var submitButton: some View {
        Button("Submit") {self.setsViewModel.postSets()}
    }
}
```

The setsViewModel just makes a post request to a backend API, and has the relevant structs (whole SetsViewModel requested):

```
struct Session: Codable {
    var session_id: Int
    var workout_id: Int 
    var sets: [mySet] = []
}

struct mySet: Hashable, Codable {
    var exercise_id: Int = -1
    var weight: Int = -1
    var reps: Int = -1
    var quality: Int = -1
    var rep_speed: Int = -1
    var rest_before: Int = -1
    var note: String = ""
}

class SetsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var tokenFetcher = TokenFetcher()
    var session: Session
    var exercise: Exercise
    
    init(tokenFetcher: TokenFetcher = TokenFetcher(), session_id: Int, workout_id: Int, exercise: Exercise) {
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.tokenFetcher = tokenFetcher
        self.session = Session(session_id:session_id, workout_id: workout_id, sets: [])
        
        for _ in 1...exercise.set_number {
            session.sets.append(mySet())
        }
    }
    
    
    func postSets() {
        self.tokenFetcher.getToken()
        
        print("Adding sets with sesion id", session.session_id)
        guard let url = URL(string: (self.tokenFetcher.ngrokUrl + "/Set"))
        else {
            print("Error: Something wrong with url.")
            return
        }
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "Token": self.tokenFetcher.token
        ]
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        var jsonString = ""
        do {
            let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(session)
            jsonString = String(data: encodedData,
                                encoding: .utf8)!
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: something went wrong encoding sets", error)
        }
        let body = jsonString
        urlRequest.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the running app, the initial values (shown above) are displayed in the textfields, and even after changing the value, once I move to the next field, it returns to the initial -1. In addition, I can't type in the "note" text field at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dKxB.png)

Oddly enough, when I hit the submit button, all the values received by the API are the ones I manually entered, and not the initial values, except for the "note" field, which only remembers the last character entered. But even if it works, I'd like a user friendly UI that will show all the correct values before submission.

I have tried various Textfield headers, as well as different ways to pass around the variables to get it to the post call, none with any more success than above.

I'm new to Swift (and in college, so new overall), so please point out any better Views or ways to enable this behavior. In addition, please point out any ways to make this cleaner code, because I feel like I'm cheating in a lot of places here.

Edit: The values now remain in the text field, but as seen in the picture, they are instantiated to the default values. How can I make it so that they show the Title text instead?

Comment: Show the code for your `SetsViewModel`. If it is a `ObservableObject` class, then
 you should use a `@StateObject var setsViewModel = SetsViewModel()` in `SetsView` (or higher up the hierarchy) and
 pass it to the `SetView` using for example, `@ObservedObject var setsViewModel: SetsViewModel`. Read also the info in this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: You were right! I changed the session property in SetsViewModel to Published, and it works much better. Thanks!